# How to add jitter to Plotly Radar chart

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

### Challenge

I'm trying to plot:

1. a radar/spider chart with 6 categories for 1 instance
2. data for a set of other instances on the same categories

I'd like to use a scatter plot for (2), combines with a filled line for (1). Basically like this trend line, but then on a radar chart:

[image]
source: https://plotly.com/python/linear-fits/

### Current Attempt

Using plotly, I've already gotten to this:

[image: spider chart, the way it should look]

using this code:

```py
print(row_data)
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatterpolar(
          r=row_data, 
          theta=theta,
          fill=fill,
          name='testdata', # name of this trace
          line=line,
          marker=marker
    ))
```

I now want to add dots for the second part, which looks like this per dimension:

[image: fake points with jitter simulated]

I manually added some jitter here, as I cannot find a way to do this using plotly.
The code:

```py
   other_row_data = np.random.rand(6*6) * 100
    other_theta = [*dimension_labels] * 6

    fig.add_trace(go.Scatterpolar(
          mode='markers',
          r=other_row_data, 
          # theta=other_theta,
          theta0=45,
          dtheta=0.1,
          # fill=fill,
          # name=name, # name of this trace
          line=None,
          marker=marker
    ))
```

The next step is to combine different plots. Combining the two above gives me this:

[image: combined plot which introduces wrong axes]

which is problematic, as both the numerical and categorical axes are now mixed. Is it possible to overlay two of these charts with different axes?

### Questions

- how do I add jitter in `go.Scatterpolar`?
- how do I combine the two different plots